# Coordinates of a vector w.r.t. basis of a vector space over $\mathbb Z_5$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is from my uni's algebra textbook.

Given vector $u=(1_5,3_5,4_5)$ and basis $B=\left \{ (2_5,3_5,4_5), (1_5,2_5,3_5), (3_5,3_5, 2_5) \right \}$, find the coordinates of the vector $u$ in the basis $B$.

I get that from the definition, the coordinates of $u$ are $(\alpha,\beta, \gamma )$ where $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are scalars from the field of the vector space.

To calculate the value of $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ I set up a system of linear equations such that

$$ u = \alpha(2_5,3_5,4_5)+ \beta(1_5,2_5,3_5) + \gamma(3_5,3_5, 2_5) $$

I solved it fairly quickly using matrix and I've come to the conclusion that $$\alpha = 1_5$$
$$\beta = 1_5$$ $$\gamma = 1_5$$

My question is - since the coordinates of the vector are elements from the field, should I chose a specific representative from $1_5$ for $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$?

Then the coordinates of $u$ would be e.g.$(1,1,1)$ or $(1,6,11)$ etc.?

Or should the coordinates of the vector $u$ be the whole congruence classes so $(1_5, 1_5, 1_5)$?

Comment: The coordinates are not scalars! They are elements of the base field, which in this case is $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis, oh. Thank you for clearing that up. But they have to be exact, explicit, don't they? What baffles me is that (the way I see it) $1_5$ represents a set of numbers and I think that vector coordinates should be specific. Which is why I'm not sure whether it's acceptable to say that the coordinates of $u$ are $(1_5, 1_5, 1_5)$.

Comment: $1_5$ is an equivalence class. So formally, $1_5 = \{k: k\equiv 1 \pmod{5}\}$. The set of all $5$ possible equivalence classes modulo $5$ forms a field over which we are considering a vector space.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis The scalars of a vector space are literally the elements of the field though? So the coordinates are scalars no?

Comment: @Chris the coordinates are scalars as you suggest since they're elements of the base field. If $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is defined as $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ then you should use the equivalence classes since they are the elements of the field.